# Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 129

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have added the following code to the lambda function to get a part of a zip file uploaded to my s3 bucket.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const file = require('fs').createWriteStream('part1');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'myBucketName',
        Key: 'myFolder/testZip.zip',
        Range: 'bytes=0-3652539'
    };
    s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
};
```

The response to the lambda is throwing an error as follows.

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: c1e4d549-b4f5-47b7-bcde-bc9a31faf731 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 129",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError"
}
```

Please Help me to download the chunk i have mentioned from lambda.

Comment: Does your function have permissions to access s3?

Comment: yes @Marcin I have given access to read from the s3 bucket